# How to forward/redirect only the root of a url using tuckey?

Tags: url, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Using Tuckey, if I only wanted to forward /abc to /xyz.html but leave /abc/def or anything else alone, how would I do that?

Basically only /abc itself should be redirected, and any pages under /abc are uneffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define explicit end of you path with regexp in your `<from>` element.

For example

```
<urlrewrite>

    <rule match-type="regex">
        <condition type="method">GET</condition>
        <from>^/abc$</from>
        <to type="redirect">/xyz.html</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

So this will redirect only `/abc` (well also `/abc/`) to the target `/xyz.html` URL, the rest will not be matched therefore will not he handled.